# How to get process's grandparent id

Tags: python, linux, process, subprocess

How can i get process id of the current process's parent?
In general given a process id how can I get its parent process id?
e.g. os.getpid() can be used to get the proccess id, and os.getppid() for the parent, how do I get grandparent,

My target is linux(ubuntu) so platform specific answers are ok.

Comment: yes and better would be os.pnid(pid, N) or just os.getppid(pid)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

linux specific:

```
os.popen("ps -p %d -oppid=" % os.getppid()).read().strip()
```

Comment: Naturally, that does not work on windows unless you have cygwin installed.

Answer (score 24):

By using psutil ( https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil ):

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.Process().ppid()
2335
>>> psutil.Process().parent()
<psutil.Process (pid=2335, name='bash', cmdline='bash') at 140052120886608>
>>>
```

Comment: This is the much more reliable answer, psutil is a lifesaver.

Comment: it should be `os.getppid()` instead of `os.getpid()`. Use `os.getppid()` instead of `psutil.Process(os.getpid()).ppid()` (to return *parent's* pid). *"To get process's grandparent id"* as OP asks, use `psutil.Process(os.getppid()).ppid()` (notice: `getppid()`, not `getpid()`).

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can do this in a portable Python fashion. But there are two possibilities.

1. The information is available from the `ps` command so you could analyze that.
2. If you have a system with the `proc` file systems, you can open the file `/proc/<pid>/status` and search for the line containing `PPid:`, then do the same for that PID.

For example the following script will get you your PID, PPID and PPPID, permissions willing:

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=$$
ppid=$(grep PPid: /proc/${pid}/status | awk '{print $2'})
pppid=$(grep PPid: /proc/${ppid}/status | awk '{print $2'})
echo ${pid} ${ppid} ${pppid}
ps -f -p "${pid},${ppid},${pppid}"
```

produces:

```
3269 3160 3142
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
pax       3142  2786  0 18:24 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
root      3160  3142  0 18:24 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
root      3269  3160  0 18:34 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./getem.sh
```

Obviously, you'd have to open those files with Python.

Comment: +1 good working example, but pixelbeat's answer works easily, any caveat there?

Comment: No, pixelbeat's looks fine and, in fact, I've upvoted it since it's a tad simpler than my method - I wasn't aware of those options to ps, having come from the *very* early UNIX days :-)

Comment: I edited your answer (the ps line). Using grep to filter ps output can give incorrect results (think if pppid was 1, for example).
The -p option, by the way, is quite old.

Comment: No problems, ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ, that was really just to show that the three figures were correct, not actually part of the answer. But I'll be using that -p option from now on in lieu of grep.

Answer (score 3):

```
from __future__ import with_statement

def pnid(pid=None, N=1):
    "Get parent (if N==1), grandparent (if N==2), ... of pid (or self if not given)"
    if pid is None:
        pid= "self"

    while N > 0:
        filename= "/proc/%s/status" % pid
        with open(filename, "r") as fp:
            for line in fp:
                if line.startswith("PPid:"):
                    _, _, pid= line.rpartition("\t")
                    pid= pid.rstrip() # drop the '\n' at end
                    break
            else:
                raise RuntimeError, "can't locate PPid line in %r" % filename
        N-= 1

    return int(pid) # let it fail through


>>> pnid()
26558
>>> import os
>>> os.getppid()
26558
>>> pnid(26558)
26556
>>> pnid(N=2)
26556
>>> pnid(N=3)
1
```

Comment: btw, I've had people often ask me why I don't follow PEP-8 and never use a space after a name when assigning to it; it's an old habit I developed for C code and kept it; it's been years since I last got bitten by a "=" instead of "==" bug (or syntax error).

Comment: +1 for pnid, but wouldn't recursive "ps -p %d -oppid=" % pid would be much shorter and clear

Comment: This is a single process python script; I find a recursive `ps` more appropriate for a shell script. I don't treat python as a generic /bin/sh replacement. Thanks for the "+1" in your comment, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this portably in the general case.

You need to get this information from the process list (e.g. through the `ps` command), which is obtained in a system-specific way.

Comment: don't think he cares about portability

Answer (score 0):

I looked this up for an assignment and didn't find what I was looking for, so I will post here. I know this is very obvious, but it stumped me for a moment. If you are the one writing the grandparent's code, you can just:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  int grandpa = getpid();
  int id = fork();
  if (id == 0) {
    int id2 = fork();
    if (id2 == 0) {
      printf("I am the child process C and my pid is %d. My parent P has pid %d. My grandparent G has pid %d.\n", getpid(), getppid(), grandpa);
    } else {
      wait(NULL);
      printf("I am the parent process P and my pid is %d. My parent G has pid %d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
    }
  } else {
    wait(NULL);
    printf("I am the grandparent process G and my pid is %d.\n", getpid());
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a POSIX-compliant 'ps' command, which allows you to specify the columns you want, like this:
`ps -o pid,ppid`

You could then try:

```
import os
import re

ps = os.popen("ps -o pid,ppid")
ps.readline()    # discard header
lines = ps.readlines()
ps.close

procs = [ re.split("\s+", line.strip()) for line in lines ]

parent = {}
for proc in procs:
    parent[ int(proc[0]) ] = int(proc[1])
```

Now you can do:

```
parent[ parent[pid] ]
```

You could even write a function to list a process' ancestors:

```
def listp(pid):
    print(pid)
    if parent.has_key(pid):
        listp( parent[pid] )
```

Comment: line.split() will work instead of re.split(r"\s+", line.strip()). The default split() splits on \s+ and removes leading and trailing whitespace.