# Communicating with root child process launched with osascript "with administrator privileges"

Tags: python, macos, subprocess, applescript, osascript

How can I pass messages between a parent process that launches a child process as root using Apple Script and stdin/stdout?

I'm writing an anti-forensics GUI application that needs to be able to do things that require root permissions on MacOS. For example, shutting down the computer.

For security reasons, I do not want the user to have to launch the entire GUI application as root. Rather, I want to just spawn a child process with root permission and a very minimal set of functions.

Also for security reasons, I do not want the user to send my application its user password. That authentication should be handled by the OS, so only the OS has visibility into the user's credentials. I read that [the best way to do this with Python on MacOS is to leverage `osascript`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5747007/1174102).

Unfortunately, for some reason, communication between the parent and child process breaks when I launch the child process using `osascript`. Why?

### Example with sudo

First, let's look at how it *should* work.

Here I'm just using `sudo` to launch the child process. Note I can't use `sudo` for my use-case because I'm using a GUI app. I'm merely showing it here to demonstrate how communication between the processes *should* work.

##### Parent (spawn_root.py)

The parent python script launches the child script `root_child.py` as root using `sudo`.

Then it sends it a command `soft-shutdown\n` and waits for the response

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess, sys

proc = subprocess.Popen(
 [ 'sudo', sys.executable, 'root_child.py' ],
 stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True
)

print( "sending soft-shutdown command now" )
proc.stdin.write( "soft-shutdown\n" )
proc.stdin.flush()
print( proc.stdout.readline() )

proc.stdin.close()
```

##### Child (root_child.py)

The child process enters an infinite loop listening for commands (in our actual application, the child process will wait in the background for the command from the parent; it won't usually just get the `soft-shutdown` command immediately).

Once it does get a command, it does some sanity checks. If it matches `soft-shutdown`, then it executes `shutdown -h now` with `subprocess.Popen()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os, sys, re, subprocess

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # loop and listen for commands from the parent process
    while True:

        command = sys.stdin.readline().strip()

        # check sanity of recieved command. Be very suspicious
        if not re.match( "^[A-Za-z_-]+$", command ):
            sys.stdout.write( "ERROR: Bad Command Ignored\n" )
            sys.stdout.flush()
            continue

        if command == "soft-shutdown":
            try:
                proc = subprocess.Popen(
                 [ 'sudo', 'shutdown', '-h', 'now' ],
                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True
                )
                sys.stdout.write( "SUCCESS: I am root!\n" )
                sys.stdout.flush()
            except Exception as e:
                sys.stdout.write( "ERROR: I am not root :'(\n" )
                sys.stdout.flush()
                sys.exit(0)

            continue
        else:
            sys.stdout.write( "WARNING: Unknown Command Ignored\n" )
            sys.stdout.flush()
            continue
```

##### Example execution

This works great. You can see in this example execution that the shutdown command runs without any exceptions thrown, and then the machine turns off.

```
user@host ~ % ./spawn_root.py  
sending soft-shutdown command now
SUCCESS: I am root!
...
user@host ~ % Connection to REDACTED closed by remote host.
Connection to REDACTED closed.
user@buskill:~$
```

### Example with osascript

Unfortunately, this does *not* work when you use `osascript` to get the user to authenticate in the GUI.

For example, if I change one line in the subprocess call in `spawn_root.py` from using `sudo` to using `osascript` as follows

##### Parent (spawn_root.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess, sys

proc = subprocess.Popen(
 ['/usr/bin/osascript', '-e', 'do shell script "' +sys.executable+ ' root_child.py" with administrator privileges' ],
 stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True
)

print( "sending soft-shutdown command now" )
proc.stdin.write( "soft-shutdown\n" )
proc.stdin.flush()
print( proc.stdout.readline() )

proc.stdin.close()
```

##### Child (root_child.py)

```
(no changes in this script, just use 'root_child.py' from above)
```

##### Example Execution

This time, after I type my user password into the prompt provided by MacOS, the parent gets stuck indefinitely when trying to communicate with the child.

```
user@host spawn_root_sudo_communication_test % diff simple/spawn_root.py simple_gui/spawn_root.py 
sending soft-shutdown command now
```

Why is it that I cannot communicate with a child process that was launched with `osascript`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728330/how-to-get-processs-grandparent-id

Comment: There's quite a lot here to consider. Firstly: "infinite loop"—that's automatically a no-go, so I hope your final application won't be relying on this as a substitute for a proper implementation of a notification observer. Secondly, while this won't address the underlying issue, `osascript` can shut down the compuer without root privileges: `tell app "System Events" to shut down` (or `...to restart` if you want to reboot).  As for the actual issue, both `osascript` and `do shell script` terminate once commands are executed.  If `do shell script` spawns a process, it probably orphans it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended-up solving this by abandoning `osascript` and instead calling the `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` function with [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), which is actually just what `osascript` does indirectly.

### Parent (spawn_root.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
################################################################################
# File:    spawn_root.py
# Version: 0.1
# Purpose: Launch a child process with root permissions on MacOS via
#          AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(). For more info, see:
#           * https://stackoverflow.com/a/74001980
#           * https://stackoverflow.com/q/73999365
#           * https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/issues/14
# Authors: Michael Altfield <michael@michaelaltfield.net>
# Created: 2022-10-15
# Updated: 2022-10-15
################################################################################

################################################################################
#                                   IMPORTS                                    #
################################################################################

import sys, ctypes, struct
import ctypes.util
from ctypes import byref

# import some C libraries for interacting via ctypes with the MacOS API
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library("c"))

# https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security
sec = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library("Security"))

################################################################################
#                                  SETTINGS                                    #
################################################################################

kAuthorizationFlagDefaults = 0

################################################################################
#                                  FUNCTIONS                                   #
################################################################################

# this basically just re-implmenets python's readline().strip() but in C
def read_from_child(io):

    # get the output from the child process character-by-character until we hit a new line
    buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(1)
    result = ''
    for x in range(1,100):

        # read one byte from the child process' communication PIPE and store it to the buffer
        libc.fread(byref(buf),1,1,io)
    
        # decode the byte stored to the buffer as ascii
        char = buf.raw[:1].decode('ascii')

        # is the character a newline?
        if char == "\n":
            # the character is a newline; stop reading
            break
        else:
            # the character is not a newline; append it to the string and continue reading
            result += char

    return result

################################################################################
#                                  MAIN BODY                                   #
################################################################################

################################
# EXECUTE CHILD SCRIPT AS ROOT #
################################

auth = ctypes.c_void_p()
r_auth = byref(auth)
sec.AuthorizationCreate(None,None,kAuthorizationFlagDefaults,r_auth)

exe = [sys.executable,"root_child.py"]
args = (ctypes.c_char_p * len(exe))()
for i,arg in enumerate(exe[1:]):
    args[i] = arg.encode('utf8')

io = ctypes.c_void_p()

print( "running root_child.py")
err = sec.AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(auth,exe[0].encode('utf8'),0,args,byref(io))
print( "err:|" +str(err)+ "|" )
print( "root_child.py executed!")

##################################
# SEND CHILD "MALICIOUS" COMMAND #
##################################

print( "sending malicious command now" )

# we have to explicitly set the encoding to ascii, else python will inject a bunch of null characters (\x00) between each character, and the command will be truncated on the receiving end
#  * https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/issues/14#issuecomment-1279643513
command = "Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;\n".encode(encoding="ascii")
libc.fwrite(command,1,len(command),io)
libc.fflush(io)
print( "result:|" +str(read_from_child(io))+ "|" )

################################
# SEND CHILD "INVALID" COMMAND #
################################

print( "sending invalid command now" )

command = "make-me-a-sandwich\n".encode(encoding="ascii")
libc.fwrite(command,1,len(command),io)
libc.fflush(io)
print( "result:|" +str(read_from_child(io))+ "|" )

######################################
# SEND CHILD "soft-shutdown" COMMAND #
######################################

print( "sending soft-shutdown command now" )

command = "soft-shutdown\n".encode(encoding="ascii")
libc.fwrite(command,1,len(command),io)
libc.fflush(io)
print( "result:|" +str(read_from_child(io))+ "|" )

# clean exit
libc.close(io)
sys.exit(0)
```

### Child (root_child.py)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os, time, re, sys, subprocess

def soft_shutdown():
        try:
                proc = subprocess.Popen(
                 [ 'sudo', 'shutdown', '-h', 'now' ],
                 stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True
                )
        except Exception as e:
                print( "I am not root :'(" )

if __name__ == "__main__":

        # loop and listen for commands from the parent process
        while True:

                command = sys.stdin.buffer.readline().strip().decode('ascii')

                # check sanity of recieved command. Be very suspicious
                if not re.match( "^[A-Za-z_-]+$", command ):
                        msg = "ERROR: Bad Command Ignored\n"

                        sys.stdout.buffer.write( msg.encode(encoding='ascii') )
                        sys.stdout.flush()
                        continue

                if command == "soft-shutdown":
                        try:
                                soft_shutdown()
                                msg = "SUCCESS: I am root!\n"

                        except Exception as e:
                                msg = "ERROR: I am not root :'(\n"

                else:   
                        msg = "WARNING: Unknown Command Ignored\n"

                sys.stdout.buffer.write( msg.encode(encoding='ascii') )
                sys.stdout.flush()
                continue
```

### Example Execution

```
maltfield@host communicate % ./spawn_root.py
running root_child.py
err:|0|
root_child.py executed!
sending malicious command now
result:|ERROR: Bad Command Ignored|
sending invalid command now
result:|WARNING: Unknown Command Ignored|
sending soft-shutdown command now
result:|SUCCESS: I am root!|
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "root_child.py", line 26, in <module>
    sys.stdout.flush()
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
maltfield@host communicate % 

*** FINAL System shutdown message from maltfield@host.local ***              
System going down IMMEDIATELY                                                  
                                                                               
                                                                               
Connection to REDACTED closed by remote host.
Connection to REDACTED closed.
maltfield@buskill:~$
```

## Additional Information

### Security

Note that `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` has been deprecated by apple in-favor of an alternatve that requires you to pay them money. Unfortunately, there's some misinformation out there that `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` is a huge security hole. While it's true that using `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` *incorrectly* can cause security issues, **it is *not* inherently insecure** to use it.

Obviously, any time you run something as root, you need to be very careful!

`AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` is deprecated, but it *can* be used safely. But it can also be used unsafely!

It basically boils down to: do you actually know what you're running as root? If the script you're running as root is located in a Temp dir that has world-writeable permissions (as a *lot* of MacOS App installers have done historically), then any malicious process could gain root access.

To execute a process as root safely:

1. Make sure that the permissions on the process-to-be-launched are root:root 0400 (or writeable only by root)
2. Specify the absolute path to the process-to-be-launched, and don't allow any malicious modification of that path

### Further Reading

1. [`AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` Reference Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1540038-authorizationexecutewithprivileg)
2. [Get root dialog in Python on Mac OS X, Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747007/get-root-dialog-in-python-on-mac-os-x-windows)
3. https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/issues/14
4. https://www.jamf.com/blog/detecting-insecure-application-updates-on-macos/