# How to change a processes' STDIN to the STDOUT of another process during runtime

Tags: python, macos, stdin, file-descriptor, tty

How can I change a python script's STDIN to be the STDOUT of another process in the middle of the runtime of that script?

I'm writing a python application that runs as a non-root user and that launches a child process as root using `subprocess`. Due to [complexities in how MacOS handles privilege escalation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73999365/communicating-with-root-child-process-launched-with-osascript-with-administrato), the child process's parent process is no longer the python script that created it, the child looses its tty, and the stdin/stdout communication gets broken between parent & child.

Since the child process is root, I can find the actual parent processes' PID and TTY using `ps`

```
result = os.popen( 'ps -eo "pid, tty, command" | grep -iE "[s]pawn_root.py"' ).read().splitlines().pop().split()

pid = result[0]
tty = result[1]
```

And I was successfully able to attach the stdin of the child process to the tty of the parent process as follows

```
sys.stdin = open( '/dev/' +str(tty), 'r' )
```

Unfortunately, it seems that attaching to the tty of the parent process is not the same as attaching to the STDOUT of the parent process. I guess it's a path to a different file descriptor, somehow.

If I have a python process A running as root on MacOS, how can I attach that processes' STDIN to the STDOUT of process B, given the PID or Command name of process B?

Comment: Please reconsider `ps | grep` -- it's error-prone at the best of times, and for Python there are 3rd-party libraries that do a better job; see https://pypi.org/project/psutil/

Comment: That said -- _in general_, you need to redirect programs' IO _before_ those programs are started. There are exceptions, but they're platform-specific and painful, and the workarounds I personally recall seeing (in addition to being utter hacks) were Linux-only.

Comment: Definitely. This is not production code. I'm first just trying to make it work :)

Comment: GUI privilege escalation through the OS is already platform-specific, so this solution is limited to MacOS

Comment: What's the context? I wonder if there might be an alternative -- something like having your program's stdout be tee'd to a script that can be signaled to switch from bitbucketing the output to redirecting it to a FIFO, or running it inside a tmux-style tool, or similar.

Comment: Context is this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73999365/communicating-with-root-child-process-launched-with-osascript-with-administrato

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248663/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-michael-altfield).